# Game Maker: How do I make a score display move with the view?

Tags: camera, game-maker, hud

I have drawn everything needed to the screen including a HUD for the score, but I have my room set to follow my player: When the camera follows the player, the score HUD stays doesn't scroll with him!

How do I make the score display follow along with the player also?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to set the score position relative to the view position every update event.

Some basic pseudo code from what I remember of GML.

```
    score.x = view[0].x + 15;
    score.y = view[0].y + 15;
```

You can do something similar with the drag and drop interface, but I haven't touched GameMaker for years so I can't help you with that.

Comment: I think there is an option "relative to view" when you inspect the object in the room. Not sure though, been a few years for me as well (even before YoYo took over).

Comment: There's a new Draw GUI event that would be worth looking into: http://www.yoyogames.com/tech_blog/9

It would take care of doing all that relative stuff for you

Answer (score 2):

I added this to event draw, of the object Score and it worked for me

```
x= view_xview[0] + 320;
y= view_yview[0];
draw_set_font(fnt_score);
draw_set_color(c_white);
draw_text(x, y, (score));
```

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE, Simon! Looking at your code, it's not obvious what everything actually does - for example, why is 320 added to `view_xview[0]`? It'd be great if you could edit your answer to explain your code.

Answer (score 0):

@Simon was pretty close.

If you are trying to draw relative to the View that is *Enabled* you can use `view_xview[view_current], view_yview[view_current]`.

For most situations you can get away with using `view_xview[0]` because most games do not utilize multiple views.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Draw GUI event for this particular problem.

I needed some left/right arrows on my screen to control player movement.  I placed two buttons in the room, added a Draw event to each with nothing in it.  I then added a Draw GUI event, with

```
draw_self();
```

as the only code in the event.

However, this only works for the full version.